# Does anyone know the name of the music from 4:46 onwards in Senki Zesshou Symphogear GX episode 12?

Tags: music, senki-zesshou-symphogear

Does anyone know the name of the music from around 4:46 onwards in Senki Zesshou Symphogear GX episode 12? It starts after Maria says "10 thousand plans".

Answer (score 1):

Another Symphogear aficionado!

This piece is "S2CA/Voltage Maximum", [*Symphogear G* OST 1](http://vgmdb.net/album/40295) track #7. The first use of this piece was in episode 2 of *Symphogear G*, when Tsubasa/Chris/Hibiki use S2CA Triburst for the first time.